# Looking for manga that I have little to no information on

Tags: story-identification, manga

So I was just reading a manga as you do... and then I saw a picture in the comments and I’m like ooh that looks like a good read, so I looked at the replies to that comment and someone said the sauce but I didn’t get anything they said it was:
Hero where are you when we needed you the most

[image] [image: 2nd one]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because either manga does not appear to contain science-fiction or fantasy elements.

Comment: @Jenayah - I've found the manga from the first image and it appears to be on topic (isekai, monsters, talking animals, there's an Elf)

Comment: @Orange_Guy: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7):

The two images are actually from two different mangas. The first one is from [Mofumofu to Isekai Slow Life o Mezashimasu](https://myanimelist.net/manga/126681/Mofumofu_to_Isekai_Slow_Life_wo_Mezashimasu?q=Mofumofu%20to%20Isekai%20Slow%20Life%20o%20Mezashimasu&cat=manga). Note that it's been overtyped to make it creepier.

[image]

> The place where the overworked adolescent man was dropped was a different world. Having been turned into a boy Arito, while playing with monsters, he is led by the old elven man Orst and becomes familiar with the life of the magical forest.

[image]

---

The second is from [Let's be an Adventurer! ~Defeating Dungeons with a Skill Board (Boukenka ni Narou!: Skill Board de Dungeon Kouryaku)](https://myanimelist.net/manga/116008/Boukenka_ni_Narou__Skill_Board_de_Dungeon_Kouryaku).

> *Haruki Karaboshi has no presence as far as can be recognized, and so he became an adventurer with only the desire to "stand out." One day, a dungeon appeared under his home in Hokkaido. Coincidentally, he picked up a "Skill Board" with which he can spend skill points to increase his growth rate. Is it possible to become a popular person by obsessively diving into your home dungeon every day?*

[image]

Comment: Since the notification may not be sent, Orange_Guy has revised their question to remove the second image.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Not sure why. Rolled back